# Django Filter latest files

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model like,

```
class Type(CommonBase):
    """
        Allowed document types
    """
    DOCUMENT_CLASS_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'Credit Card'),
        ('D', 'Debit Card'),
        ('SD', 'Supporting Documents'),
    )
    MODEL_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('person', 'Person'),
        ('bank', 'Bank'),
        ('all', 'All')
    )
    document_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document_class = models.CharField(choices=DOCUMENT_CLASS_CHOICES, max_length=3, default='C')
    model_type = models.CharField(choices=MODEL_TYPE_CHOICE, max_length=50, default='person')

class Document(CommonBase):
  
    doc_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    uploaded_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

I can upload Multiple credit card or multiple debit card details against the same user.

So if a user has uploaded 2 credit card documents and 3 debit card documents.
I need to get all the documents uploaded against that user but there should be only one credit card and debit card document which  is the latest

```
docs = Documrnt.objects.filter(user=user)
```

this gives me all the documents(2 credit card docs and 3 debit card docs) uploaded against that particular user.
But I need only the latest uploaded debit card and credit card details  in result

How the query is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the descending behavior of the **[order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)**.

**Oldest items first.**

```
Document.objects.order_by('uploaded_datetime')
```

**Newest items first.** (what you want)

```
Document.objects.order_by('-uploaded_datetime')
```

Comment: I need to get all the documents uploaded against that user but there should be only one credit card and debit card document  combination which is the latest

Comment: order_by is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
qs = Document.objects.filter(user=user)
latest_credit_card = qs.filter(doc_type__document_class='C').order_by('-id')[0]
latest_debit_card = qs.filter(doc_type__document_class='D').order_by('-id')[0]
```

Comment: in my case there is 50+ ```document_class``` ,so filtering 50 times not a good choice

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by using [lookups through relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), ordering with respect to the field you want, which is `uploaded_datetime`, and then retrieving the [last values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#last) from each query. As in the example below:

```
qs = Document.objects.filter(user=user)
latest_uploaded_credit_card = qs.filter(doc_type__document_class='C').order_by('uploaded_datetime').last()
latest_uploaded_debit_card = qs.filter(doc_type__document_class='D').order_by('uploaded_datetime').last()
```